# Why does my multiprocessing code take so long to complete in python 3.9, but not python 2.7. Code improvements?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I have some code that uses `multiprocessing` to perform some work with `apply_async` and while it is working, I update the main GUI and allow other activities to be performed.  Everything seems to work just fine in python 2.7, however, I am running into issues running the code in python 3.9.  My overall issue is that it is just not working any more, but in putting together the sample debug code below (which does work) I have noticed a significant increase in the amount of time it takes for my process to complete in 3.9 vs 2.7.

Simplified code is as follows:

```
import multiprocessing
import time
import datetime


def main():
    start_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    print('Spinning up pool')
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=10)
    vals = range(100)
    results = []
    print('Adding processes')
    runs = [pool.apply_async(calc, (x, 1), callback=results.append) for x in vals]

    print('Working...')
    while len(vals) != len(results):
        print('Results: {}'.format(results))
        time.sleep(1)

    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    print('Done')
    end_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    duration = end_time - start_time
    print('Program took {} seconds to complete'.format(duration.total_seconds()))

def calc(x, y):
    print(x + y)
    time.sleep(2)
    return(x+y)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**python 2.7:**

`Program took 48.965 seconds to complete`

**python 3.9:**

`Program took 372.522254 seconds to complete`

Is there a reason this takes so much longer in 3.9 vs 2.7?  Is there any modifications to my code to speed things up a bit?  Is there a better way to process tasks like this while waiting for a pool to finish up all the work?

Operating system is Windows 10.

Comment: There's quite a lot that has changed since 2.7, so to nail down exactly what's going on, all I can say is to profile your code (which is a little more difficult compared to single process, but definitely not impossible with the `profile` library)

Comment: Include your os in the question description

Comment: Also just based on your stripped down example, There's not a significant benefit to using `apply_asyc` over just something like `map` unless you're trying to do more work in the meantime while it's processing. It basically does the same stuff (line up all the results into a list as they are completed), without the work on your part, and potentially a bit less overhead.

Comment: I will take a look at the profile library.  Updated description to list Windows 10.  The program I am working on does a few things in the while loop; it updates progress bars for each of the processes as well as does a bit of post-process cleanup once it sees a job is complete.  I could probably move the post-processing into the job itself, but that still leaves updating of the job progress bars in there.

Comment: @Das.Rot I could not reproduce this, on 3.9 the code took 21.5s, while on 2.7 it took 21.8s, on average

Comment: @Charchit I believe I may have found my timing issue.  I was testing on two different computers and had my pool size set for my desktop, so I had more processes than I had cores available when I ran on my laptop which seems to have bogged it down significantly.  The strange thing is it was bogged down much more on 3.9 than 2.7.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a significant difference in running times between Python 3.8 and Python 2.7 on Windows. But the way I would approach solving the problem is by noting that your worker function `calc` is mostly wait time and a small amount of CPU-required calculations. So one thing you could do is to increase your pool size significantly since your processes will be in a wait state most of the time.

But better would be to use a thread pool of size 100 (since you are submitting 100 tasks) and pass to your worker function a multiprocessing pool (whose size is the number of cores you have) that can be used for performing the calculations that require actual CPU. And since it appears that your `results` list will contain return values from your worker function in *completion order*, you might as well use the `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool.imap_unordered` method rather than multiple calls to `apply_async`:

```py
import multiprocessing
import time
import datetime
from functools import partial


def main():
    start_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
    thread_pool = multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool(100)
    vals = range(100)
    worker = partial(calc, y=1, pool=pool)
    results = list(thread_pool.imap_unordered(worker, vals))
    end_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    duration = end_time - start_time
    print('Program took {} seconds to complete'.format(duration.total_seconds()))
    print(results)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    thread_pool.close()
    thread_pool.join()

def calc(x, y, pool):
    result = pool.apply(do_add, (x, y))
    print(result)
    time.sleep(2)
    return result

def do_add(x, y):
    return x + y

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Prints:

```None
4
10
9
6
...
51
27
96
87
21
Program took 2.276529 seconds to complete
[4, 10, 30, 82, 36, 70, 83, 13, 12, 46, 71, 62, 59, 16, 73, 8, 9, 80, 72, 55, 11, 7, 43, 65, 35, 19, 61, 76, 60, 3, 57, 48, 49, 6, 45, 34, 41, 33, 31, 37, 22, 29, 24, 67, 32, 18, 14, 1, 23, 2, 15, 64, 53, 58, 98, 95, 40, 47, 39, 54, 92, 89, 93, 42, 85, 38, 99, 5, 78, 74, 25, 63, 84, 56, 91, 69, 79, 50, 44, 100, 90, 86, 81, 77, 94, 68, 28, 26, 17, 20, 87, 75, 96, 66, 52, 51, 21, 88, 27, 97]
```

**Discussion**

If your worker function, `calc`, really were as trivial as above, i.e. requiring only a simple addition operation, then I would not bother even using a multiprocessing pool for doing this calculation; I would just use a multithreading pool because it would be less expensive to do the addition in `calc` compared with submitting a task to the multiprocessing queue. But assuming your *actual* worker function contains significant CPU requirements, the idea is to break out those CPU calculations into one or more new functions and only retain in your original worker function code that is thread-efficient (e.g. I/O operations, network operations, sleeping, etc., i.e. operations that put the thread into a wait state and therefore allow another thread to execute). The CPU-intensive calculations are then done by using method `apply` on the multiprocessing queue passing the new CPU-intensive functions you have created (or use method `apply_async` if you have multiple, unrelated calculations that you can perform in parallel).

Comment: Thanks @Booboo, I will give this route a try.  My actual function is calling a `subprocess.call()` that runs a different program in the background that is quite CPU intensive (i.e. maxes out a single core).  With the `ThreadPool` method above, is it possible to run code in a `while` loop between the `imap` and the `close` code?  The results are actually not important at all, I was just using them in the past to know which processes have completed so I can post process and update the gui while the other processes are still completing (in the `while` loop).

Comment: First, if your actual `calc` function is calling `subprocess.call`, which creates a new child process, then assuming that anything else that is being done by `calc` is mostly I/O, network waiting or waiting for the `subprocess.call` to complete, then there should be no need to create a multiprocessing pool for `calc` ro use. Second, after `results = list(thread_pool.imap_unordered(worker, vals)` executes, there will no longer be any threads or processes running doing work except for the main thread. So, of course you can run code following that. (more...)

Comment: The calls to `pool.close()` and `pool.join()` are just to clean up the multiprocessing pool resources when you have no further use for the pool. Omitting these calls is usually not a problem in my experience if your program is going to terminate right away. But if the program is going to do more non-pool work, it is better to free up memory resources that could be useful later. So it would be better for you to do your additional work *following* the calls to `close` and `join`. In fact, there should be the same calls made on the multithreading pool, but I omitted those originally.

Comment: So I think I maybe answered my own question; it appears `imap_unordered` blocks until everything is complete, so I can't give a status update as it's going (like the `async` code above).  The status update actually parses a log file created by the program called by the `subprocess.call`, so I the worker can't really help me gather that info either.  Overall I will have about 100 tasks (`calc`/`subprocess`) that individually only max out one core.  So I would like to divy out those tasks to 8+ cores.  The processes also take a long time, so I would like to give updates and allow updates to GUI.

Comment: Perhaps there is a different/better approach than to use pools?  It's one of those things that always worked for me in the past, but I am not sure if it was the right/wrong approach.  Now with 3.9, things are broken and I can certain retool things since I have to anyway.

Comment: `imap_unordered` does *not* block until everything completes. It returns an *iterator* that when iterated returns successive results. For example, `for result in imap_unordered(workers, vall): print('Next returned value is'. result)`. Or you can explicitly call `__next__` on the returned iterator to retrieve the next completed task result (but you must be prepared for a `StopIteration` exception when there are no more results to return). You are actually blocking because `results = list(thread_pool.imap_unordered(worker, vals))` is completly iterating the returned iterator to create a list.